# Centering text in the middle of the parent element

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:400px;width:400px;">
 <div id="example">
  Text
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to get `#example` into the center (left, right, top, and bottom) of `#wrapper`.

Comment: Do you mean "width" not "weight"?

Comment: Almost certainly means "width", updated

Answer (score 2):

I think there are multiple ways to achieve what you want. One would be:

```
#wrapper{
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#example{
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    background:blue;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SsD4Q/3/

I hope that helped somehow!

Comment: `position:relative;top:50%` does **not** center an element vertically. Also, the contents of your text will not be horizontally aligned at the center.

Comment: @RobW: You are right about top:50% (just tried it myself) and will remove it from my answer.To align a text horizontally, you can always add text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

Try giving #example `margin: 0 auto;`

The second property is the left/right margin. Auto should center it.

Edit: Sorry that this does not center vertically. I misunderstood. Please see http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html for vertical centering.

Comment: this does not center vertically

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer. It looks like you found a good article from css-tricks to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment is a tricky one unless your using tables.

I suggest you read this aritcle on centering elements.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

---

Aligning horizontally however is easy...

Assign a width and use margin:auto

```
#example {width:100px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:400px;weight:400px;">
  <div id="vertical" style="height: 50%; width: 100%; margin-top: -25px"></div>
  <div id="example" style="margin: 0 auto; height: 50px">
    Text
  </div>
  </div>
```

Set the margin-top minus half the height of the example div

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the current proposed solutions... as they rely on either displaying as table-cells, or using static heights on `#example` and negative margins.

Here is my proposal, considering `#wrapper` has fixed height:

- Set `#wrapper`'s line-height equal to its height;
- Set `#wrapper`'s text-align to center and vertical-align to center;
- Set `#example`'s display to inline-block, so it is centered vertically and horizontally but still works as a block;
- Make `#example` a `span` instead, so IE8- allows it to be inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/aneves_sw/yse9w/